# Why Libxml says invalid schema when maxInclusive have 25 or more digits?

Tags: php, xml, xsd, libxml2

Whether the 25 digits are decimal and integers or just integers, `DOMDocument::schemaValidate()` fires a warning, return false, and `libxml_get_errors();` captures the next errors:

**PHP snippet:**

```
$DD = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');
$DD -> loadXML('<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><a></a>');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$old_libxml_disable_entity_loader = libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
$DD -> schemaValidate(__DIR__ . '/schemas/schema.xsd'); // WARNING
libxml_disable_entity_loader($old_libxml_disable_entity_loader);
$errors = libxml_get_errors();

foreach ($errors as $error) { // PRINT ERRORS
    echo $error -> code . '<br>';
    echo $error -> message . '<br>';
}
```

**`DOMDocument::schemaValidate()` Generated Errors:**

Error 1824:

> Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}maxInclusive':
>   '9999999999999999999999999' is not a valid value of the
>   atomic type 'xs:decimal'. in /path/schema.xsd on line X

Error 1717:

> Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}maxInclusive': The value
>   '9999999999999999999999999' of the facet does not validate
>   against the base type '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}decimal'. in
>   /path/schema.xsd on line X

**Valid schema (invalid XML only):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="http://www.lala.com/la"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:la="http://www.lala.com/la"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:simpleType name="AmountType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
            <xs:totalDigits value="100"/>
            <xs:fractionDigits value="20"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="999999999999999999999999"/><!-- 24 DIGITS -->
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Invalid schema: WARNING + Libxml internal errors of invalid schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="http://www.lala.com/la"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:la="http://www.lala.com/la"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:simpleType name="AmountType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
            <xs:totalDigits value="100"/>
            <xs:fractionDigits value="20"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="9999999999999999999999999"/><!-- 25 DIGITS -->
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**PHP version:** 5.5.20

**Libxml version:** 2.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [W3C XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/), libxml2 can limit the range of `maxInclusive` because it is allowed to limit the range of the value space of `xs:decimal`...

[4.3.7 maxInclusive:](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-maxInclusive)

> [Definition:]   **maxInclusive** is the ·inclusive upper bound· of the
>   ·value space· for a datatype with the ·ordered· property. The value of
>   **maxInclusive** ·must· be in the ·value space· of the ·base type·.

[3.2.3 decimal](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal)

> Note:  All ·minimally conforming· processors ·must· support decimal
>   numbers with a minimum of 18 decimal digits (i.e., with a
>   ·totalDigits· of 18). However, ·minimally conforming· processors ·may·
>   set an application-defined limit on the maximum number of decimal
>   digits they are prepared to support, in which case that
>   application-defined maximum number ·must· be clearly documented.

Comment: indeed, just found it here: it limits to 24: http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Schema.pod